Can a user remove their signature on a petition made with Civi Petition?
On most non-profits websites that propose signing petitions, the automatic email that comes after the petition signature contains a link allowing the user to remove their signature from the petition if desired, e.g. :

Thank you for signing our petition "..." !
If somebody else have signed this petition with your adress, or if you want to remove your signature, just click on this link to remove your signature.

Such links are often associated with a special token (long chain of characters) that allow the user to do just that in one click.
Is such a thing possible in Civi ? I've read the documentation, the Stack Exchange site and the old forum, but haven't found anything about this.
It seems like it's possible to create a URL containing a checksum to allow the user to edit certain aspects of their profile without having to log in (see here); but this might be more than we want, and the checksum is time-limited unless a parameter is toggled.
